# How can I turn this class diagram into a data model?

Tags: sql

[This a class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeloK.png)

I want to trun it to a data model ,but I don't know how

Comment: Start with [how to create a table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp) and than [how to create FOREIGN KEY Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: I think you'r right , I have not done this in a long time I forgot the basics.      Thanks magnus